# How to remove unwanted elements and attributes from XML file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have  XML file , I want to copy it as it is , but I want to filter some unwanted elements and attributes , for example the following is the original file :

```
<root>
<e1 att="test1" att2="test2"> Value</e1>
<e2 att="test1" att2="test2"> Value 2 <inner class='i'>inner</inner></e2>
<e3 att="test1" att2="test2"> Value 3</e3>

</root>
```

After the filtration ( **e3** element and **att2** attribute have been removed ) :

```
<root>
<e1 att="test1" > Value</e1>
<e2 att="test1" > Value 2 <inner class='i'>inner</inner></e2>
</root>
```

**Notes:**

- I prefer to use ( **for-each** element instead of **apply-templates** if that possible )
- I have some problems with **xsl:element** and **xsl:attribute** since I could not write the current node name

Thanks

Comment: Why do you prefer to use `for-each` instead of `apply-templates`?

Comment: @lwburk - I think "I have some problems with xsl:element and xsl:attribute..." points to some deeper rooted issue(s).

Comment: It's not clear if you are searching for a general solution (unknown elements name) or a specific one (filter `e3`). The answer I've provided it will help you in the former case, even if it's easy to adapt it to a specific case.

Comment: @lwburk: I think for-each is more close to programming languages style than apply-templates ,

Comment: It's normal to think that `for-each` is the natural way to solve most problems at first, but I think you'll find that it's completely unnecessary as you become more familiar with XSLT.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know you'd prefer to use `for-each`, but why not use an identity transform and then override that template with what you don't want to keep?

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="e3|@att2"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces:

```
<root>
   <e1 att="test1"> Value</e1>
   <e2 att="test1"> Value 2 <inner class="i">inner</inner>
   </e2>
</root>
```

Comment: @DevNull: this won't work in case last node is somthing different from `e3`. I have generalized your answer.

Comment: @empo - That's true, but I didn't see anything in the original post about removing the last node no matter what the name was. The original post just specified that `e3` and `att2` were removed. Following your logic, I could also assume that the OP was trying to remove all elements whose name ended with "3".

Comment: @DevNull: yes, who knows unless the person directly intersted in :D!

Comment: @DevNull , @empo : Actullay I want to remove "e3" element as @DevNull said , not the last element , thanks guys , your answers are perfect

Comment: This is the correct way to solve this problem and it's a very common pattern.

Answer (score 1):

As @DevNull has shown you, using the identity transform is much easier and less verbose. Anyway, here is one possible solution with `for-each` and without `apply-templates` as you requested:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/root">
   <root>
    <xsl:for-each select="child::node()">
     <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position()=last()-1"/>
      <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@att"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="child::node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </root>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Note about using identity transform

If your situation is really what it looks like, I mean unknown name of the elements, the @DevNull won't work and you would need somthing more general like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root/child::node()[position()=last()]|@att2"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This solution will work even with last elements `e4` or `e1000`.

Comment: thank you so much , actually I want to remove the element "e3" not the last element , sorry for unclear question. your solution is perfect in the two ways .. but I chose @DevNull solution since it works fine with my situation . again , thank you so much .