# XSLT Remove all attribute for one element from xml using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following root element of a big XML file:

```
<Interchange xmlns='http://www.e2b.no/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'   
xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.e2b.no/XMLSchema Interchange'>
```

I need to get

```
<Interchange>
```

Please advise.  Here is a minimal document with the template I'm trying (I won't include my full attempts because they're much longer):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Interchange/@xmlns|@xmlns:xsi|@xsi:schemaLocation"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I will not give examples of my attempts"? That's exactly what you should do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove unwanted elements and attributes from XML file using XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985756/how-to-remove-unwanted-elements-and-attributes-from-xml-file-using-xslt)

Comment: Yes,  That's exactly what I should do

Comment: You misunderstood, I think. We expect you to try and solve problems yourself, before you post them here.

Comment: No, I understood. I said, I will not give examples of my attempts that to be more concise. I will add my implementation <xsl:template match="Interchange/@xmlns|@xmlns:xsi|@xsi:schemaLocation"/> It does not work. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Now it is clear what you are trying to do and where you went wrong.

Comment: Why did you unaccept the answer again? Please either accept the answer or say why this does not solve your problem - then, I'm willing to extend my answer of course.

Answer (score 0):

Namespace declarations are not the same as attributes. That's why you cannot exclude them from your identity templates the way you tried it.

Instead, simply match the element and output another `Interchange` that is not "burdened" with the namespaces above:

```
<xsl:template match="eb:Interchange">
  <Interchange>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Interchange>
</xsl:template>
```

Make sure that you define the required namespace in your XSLT stylesheet as well:

```
xmlns:eb='http://www.e2b.no/XMLSchema'
```

It is irrelevant which prefix (`eb` in this case) is used. But this makes sure that the `Interchange` element is found. This is crucial because `<Interchange>` and `<Interchange xmlns='http://www.e2b.no/XMLSchema'>` are *different* elements.

Comment: Your're welcome. I hope you see now that it is important to show what you have tried - even if it did not work.