# XSLT Remove all attribute for one root element from xml using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following root element of a big XML file:

```
<Interchange xmlns='http://www.e2b.no/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'   
xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.e2b.no/XMLSchema Interchange'>
```

I need to get

```
<Interchange>
```

Please advice, Sorry, I will not give examples of my attempts
I will use basic template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                          xmlns:e2b='http://www.e2b.no/XMLSchema'>
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<!-- copy everything as-is apart from exceptions below -->
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="e2b:Interchange">
<Interchange>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</Interchange>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I tested I accidentally sent big XML to input with the beginning:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<Interchange>
```

insted

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<Interchange xmlns='http://www.e2b.no/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'  
xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.e2b.no/XMLSchema Interchange'>
```

Because I answered positive on my previous question.

Please advice, any ideas.

Comment: If the answer given to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636169/xslt-remove-all-attribute-for-one-element-from-xml-using-xslt) didn't work for you, you should unaccept it and continue there, instead of opening a new, similar, question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                          xmlns:e2b='http://www.e2b.no/XMLSchema'
 exclude-result-prefixes="e2b">



<!-- copy everything as-is apart from exceptions below -->
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="e2b:*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/e2b:Interchange">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That approach is necessary to transform the element from the `e2b` namespace to no namespace.